# JSF : java.lang.ClassCastException: entity.Commandeclient cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;

Tags: java, jpa

Here's my class CommandeclientFacade.java:

```
public List<Object[]> findCommandeclient() {
    return em.createQuery("Select c FROM Commandeclient c").getResultList();
}
```

And my bean CommandeclientMB.java:

```
Resultat = CommandeclientFC.findCommandeclient();
for (Object[] com : Resultat) {
}
```

The problem is:

> entity.Commandeclient cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;

IMPORTANT: i want convert the resultat of the class to object to let me use it in the for-loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getResultList()` gives you a list of objects (`Commandeclient`), whereas you have it as a list of `Object[]`.

```
public List<Commandeclient> findCommandeclient() {
    return em.createQuery("Select c FROM Commandeclient c").getResultList();
}
Resultat = CommandeclientFC.findCommandeclient();
for (Commandeclient com : Resultat) {
}
```

Should be what your code should look like.

Comment: Thank You :D
Your answers let me think in  other way to make it ^^